# how to make <!--more--> function in RSS feed like it does in posts

Tags: rss, read-more

I'm dealing with an RSS feed problem that is making me crazy. I have begun manually incorporating  in my recent blog posts in order to cut off the post at the desired spot and entice people to click to the post page in order to finish reading. In other words, I'm manually specifying the length of the teaser by inserting .

My site works exactly how I want it to work, but I want my RSS feed to function in the same way. In other words, I want the post in my RSS feed to cut off at  and link to the original post so subscribers have to visit my site to continue reading.

I know that this is possible because some of my favorite blogs work this way (for example, 101cookbooks.com and smittenkitchen.com). I don't want to just see a text excerpt/summary feed. I want the text and photos up to the  code to display in my feed exactly as they do on my home page! Please help! I've googled and googled and I can't find the answer.

Thank you,
Kate

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to a [code snippet](http://www.peterrknight.com/how-to-truncate-your-wordpress-rss-feed-at-the-more-tag/) that you can put in functions.php to do what you want.

By default, the RSS feed either shows the entire article when set to show "Full Text" in the Reading Settings or it shows the Excerpt field when set to "Summary."

Support for the  tag can only be done through a plugin or theme snippet.

====

EDIT: I wasn't thrilled with how that snippet above worked and so went searching more. I'll leave it for posterity, but I'd look into using [this snippet](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/rss-feed-before-the-more-tag?replies=8#post-1593916) instead. It actually enables the "more" feature rather than trying to recreate it. I haven't tried it, but it looks right.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, mrwweb! I'm so glad someone finally gets what I'm trying to do. I followed the instructions on your page and inserted the code in my functions.php, but it did not truncate the RSS items at the <!--more--> tag! Does the code have to go in a certain spot in functions.php?

Comment: @kate It won't update your old posts, if that's what you're looking for, but will only affect new ones. You'll also need to make sure to edit that snippet to use text you like.

Comment: That's terrific! I'll check my feed after I publish my next post. Thank you SO MUCH for your help.